# How to make redirection not random and follow the order?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have this code with which I intend that every time the same user reloads the page it redirects it to a different URL, the problem is that sometimes it redirects to the same URL in the list and what I am looking for is to follow an order.
For example: url1, url2, url3.

```js
var URLlist = ["url1.html", "url2.html", "url3.html"];
var reDelay = 0000;
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = URLlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * URLlist.length)];
}, reDelay);
```

Comment: You would need to keep track of what the user has visited.  Using localStorage, a cookie, or a state container in your app would help you achieve this.

Comment: Do not use random to select one. Shuffle the URLList after creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the current URL of the page by using `window.location.href` and filter it from the list of URL's. Then only the options that are **not** the current page can be selected as the new URL.

```js
/**
 * Example current URL.
 * The value of this should be the URL of the current page.
 * Like window.location.href
 */
var currentURL = 'url2.html'; 

// Filter the current page from the list.
var URLlist = ["url1.html","url2.html","url3.html"].filter(url => url !== currentURL); 
var reDelay = 1000;
setTimeout(function(){
  var newURL = URLlist[Math.floor(Math.random()* URLlist.length)];
  // window.location = newURL;
  console.log(newURL);
}, reDelay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
var URLlist = ["url1.html","url2.html","url3.html"];
//URLs a las que el usuario ha sido redireccionado.
var urlsRedireccionado = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("urls_redireccionado")) || [];

var reDelay = 0000;

setTimeout(function(){
    //La siguiente URL en el orden en que han sido agregadas en la variable URLlist
    var next = URLlist.find(u => !urlsRedireccionado.some(ur => ur == u));
    //Si faltan URL por redireccionar
    if(next) {
        urlsRedireccionado.push(next);
        window.localStorage.setItem("urls_redireccionado", JSON.stringify(urlsRedireccionado));
        window.location = next;
    } else {
        //Para que la proxima vez que recargue sea redirigido a todas las URL anteriores
        window.localStorage.removeItem("urls_redireccionado");

        //Redireccionado a todas partes
    }

}, reDelay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a counter which will help you keep a track of URL position and a condition that will help you reset counter to the first position in the array when you are out of URLs.

```js
var URLlist = ['url1.html', 'url2.html', 'url3.html'];
var counter = 0;
var reDelay = 2000;

setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = URLlist[counter];
    counter++;
    URLlist[counter] === undefined ? counter = 0 : counter;
}, reDelay);
```